# Ionic + Leaflet How Can I clear an existing layer before redrawing it?

Tags: ionic-framework, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I am using Leaflet with my ionic app to draw polygons on an uploaded floor plan map. Everything is working great. I am having trouble clearing the existing polygons before I re-draw the map - which is causing multiple layers getting stacked up.

Here is what I am doing so far:

**.ts file**

```
ngOnInit() {
    // get saved polygons from db
   ...
   .subscribe((res => {
       res.forEach(data => {
           this.drawPolygon(data);
       });
   }));
}

...


// Draw each of the saved polygons
drawPolygon(data) {
    if (data.polygon.geometry) {
        let shape = {
            polygon: data,
            type: data.polygon.type,
            geometry: {
                type: data.polygon.geometry.type,
                coordinates: data.polygon.geometry.coordinates
            },
            properties: {}
        };

        // Remove all existing layers


        L.geoJSON(shape, {
            onEachFeature: this.onEachFeature.bind(this),
        }).addTo(this.myMay);
    }
}


// onEachFeature method to trigger popover
onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on('click', event => {
        let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create('MyComponent', {
        layer: feature
    });

    popover.present();

    }, this);
}
```

I've tried various methods of `removeLayer` or `clearLayers` to even removing the map with no luck. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

If I do a page refresh after everything, all of the additional layers are removed - and the single layer remains as it should.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all layers the following code should work, assuming your map object is called myMap:

```
myMap.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    myMap.removeLayer(layer);
});
```

I wouldn't put it in drawPolygon though - ngOnInit or where that is called from seems a better place to clear the map data before adding new.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I must have something set up goofy. I am able to remove my map layer with your help - but none of the drawn layers (polygons).